# How to compare user input with content of text file

Tags: bash

I am trying to make a shell script which compares user input with content of text file list.txt. If content matches it will return message and if not it will return $input 
I tried this

```
if [ "$input" == "$(cat list.txt)" ]; then
      echo " user exists" 
else 
      echo "$input"
fi
```

But every time I run this program it returns user input value, even if user exists in list.txt. What am I doing wrong? This runs perfectly fine when I give hard coded string values to variables and insert those variables in if statement. But when I try to compare with list.txt I get wrong output

Comment: Looks like your file `list.txt` contains list of users and `$input` contains 1 user - definitely you have different strings, that's why your comparison return false.

Comment: You are right. Now I have to find a way to compare input array and list.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `list.txt` contains a list of users then you can't do a straight string comparison. Comparing a single user name to a list of users will fail. Instead, you need to search the file for a match:

```
if grep -q "$input" list.txt; then
    echo 'user exists'
fi
```